# Laravel: Running a database migration on a production server

Tags: laravel, database, migration

I have a local repo for development and a production server in Laravel.

When I work locally, as the project grows, so does the DB. Therefore I keep adding new migrations that sometimes change existing tables. Locally I can refresh / recreate tables and seed without worrying.

However when I want to update the production DB where actual data is stored, what's the best method? If I need to update an existing table I cannot just drop and recreate it, as data would be lost. And if I run the migration directly, I get an error like "table already exists". So I end up manually adding the fields in the DB, which I don't think it's the best way to go.

Comment: you can create a new migration to update the table instead of dropping/rollbacking the existing table's migration

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#modifying-columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned, you can create migrations to update the columns without dropping the tables. And [the 'Modifying columns' docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#modifying-columns) provide a clear explanation for this. However that is docs for modifying columns, if you want to modify tables instead of columns, you can use [the 'Updating tables' docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#updating-tables)

This uses the SchemaBuilder to do various things, for example, adding columns in an existing table:

```
Schema::table('table_name'), function ($table) {
  $table->string('new_column')->after('existing_column');
  // however you can leave the ->after() part out, this just specifies that the
  // new column should be insterted after the specified column.
});
```

Or delete a column from an existing table

```
Schema::table('table_name'), function ($table) {
  $table->dropColumn('new_column');
});
```

You can also `rename` but I'll leave it to you to explore the docs further.